# Strip unnecessary whitespace and html comments from Tornado-rendered Pages

Tags: python, tornado

I am using tornado and the tornado templating engine. Even when debug is set to False, tornado-rendered pages still have HTML comments and unnecessary whitespace in them. Is there a setting to automatically strip this out when rendering pages (essentially minifying the rendered pages)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tornado doesn't know anything about html comments, so any html comments will be passed through as-is.  (You can use `{# #}` to add comments to your templates).  There is limited support for stripping whitespace, which is enabled by default based on file extension (.html and .js).  There's also a half-implemented compress_whitespace setting, although there is no clean way to set it unless you implement your own template loader.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the [`compress_whitespace`](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/template.html#tornado.template.Template) flag for a `Template` (or to `render`/`render_string`) to automatically remove extraneous whitespace. I don't believe there's an option to strip out comments built-in.

Comment: Is there a way to set this globally for all templates?